# Extract single substring from each row of the series using regular expression with named capturing groups in the alternation operator

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas, pcre

Given:

1. Pandas series `src` of strings;
2. Complex regular expression (for simplicity let `'^(?:\d+ (\w+)|(\w+) \d+)$'`) that can extract some **single** substring (let
   each string matches regex).

The goal: get pandas series (i.e. "column") that has extracted substrings from source series.

For example (note, this is simplified example - in the real case regular expression is more complex, i.e. it's difficult to rewrite it to regex with single capturing group):

```
src = pandas.Series(['1 s', '2 ss', 'sss 3', '4 ssss'])  # source data
result = pandas.Series(['s', 'ss', 'sss', 'ssss'])  # need to get
```

I tried the direct solution using [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
result = src.str.extract('^(?:\d+ (\w+)|(\w+) \d+)$')
```

but it returns DataFrame with 2 columns where each row has `NaN` and  required substring:

```
      0    1
0     s  NaN
1    ss  NaN
2   NaN  sss
3  ssss  NaN
```

I tried use named capturing groups:

```
result = src.str.extract('^(?:\d+ (?P<field>\w+)|(?P<field>\w+) \d+)$')
```

but I got error:

> sre_constants.error: redefinition of group name 'field' as group 2

I don't know how to solve this problem when I use alternation operator...

And the next question: how  to solve the same problem when string in the series does not match regex? It's necessary to return `NaN` in such case.

**UPDATE**: I found solution using [`str.cat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.cat.html#pandas.Series.str.cat):

```
result = src.str.extract('^(?:\d+ (\w+)|(\w+) \d+)$')
result = result[0].str.cat(result[1], na_rep='')
```

But it requires additional actions... So I still find more elegant solution without changing number of capturing groups in the regex.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a non-capturing group for the before/after part of the string, and just one capturing group. Make both non-capturing groups (before, after) optional. You won't detect erroneous lines this way, but it should get you what you need:

```
r"^(?:\d+\s+)?(\w+)(?:\s+\d+)?$"
```

Now, your true data is more complex. Consider adding a "looking at" zero-width assertion that defines the "correct" structure of your data. This will require the field be 'valid', according to whatever regex you already have. *You have already done this work,* you just need to put (?=...) around the regex, and convert capture groups to non-capture groups.

Next, separate all the alternate cases into before/capture/after sets. You have *already done this work,* you just have to organize the sets.

Now unify the before sets and the after sets with alternation, and a non-capturing group. Unify the "capture" sets with alternation and a capturing group. If possible, eliminate redundancy (two alternatives with the same pattern).

If your regex was something like:

```
r"A(B)C|D(E)F|G(H)I|J(K)L"
```

You convert that to a look-ahead pattern:

```
r"(?=A(?:B)C|D(?:E)F|G(?:H)I|J(?:K)L)"
```

You create a non-capturing "before" alternation:

```
r"(?:A|D|G|J)"
```

And a non-capturing "after" alternation:

```
r"(?:C|F|I|L)"
```

Finally, a capturing "capture" alternation:

```
r"(C|E|H|K)"
```

Put them all together:

```
r"(?=A(?:B)C|D(?:E)F|G(?:H)I|J(?:K)L)(?:A|D|G|J)(C|E|H|K)(?:C|F|I|L)"
```

It's ugly as can be, and you'll probably want to use embedded comments to document it, but it will work.

Comment: As I note in the question, I offer simple example of regex and data. Not all regexs can be easy rewritten using only 1 capture group.

Comment: Lookahead and lookbehind have the important disadvantage: they cannot contain variable length regexs.

Comment: `>>> print(re.findall("(?=a*b)(a+)", "cdacaabaaadaaaabaaaaeaaaaabbb"))

['aa', 'aaaa', 'aaaaa']`

True for look-behind, but not for look-ahead (at least in 3.5 on my Mac).